# How to sort dictionary by longest to shortest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary that looks like this

```
d = {
    'USA': ['US', 'USA', 'United States'],
    'BRA': ['Brazil', 'BR'],
    'DEU': ['Germany', 'German', 'French', 'France', 'FR', 'UK', ' United Kingdom']
}
```

I am trying to sort by longest to shortest (list length) and I found that this is the way to do that but it is not sorting properly.

```
srt = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

My output is:

```
[('USA', ['US', 'USA', 'United States']), ('DEU', ['Germany', 'German', 'French', 'France', 'FR', 'UK', ' United Kingdom']), ('BRA', ['Brazil', 'BR'])]
```

Where the Key 'DEU' should be first in the list not second? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the list length in the lambda, like this:

```
srt = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

which will produce:

```
[('DEU', ['Germany', 'German', 'French', 'France', 'FR', 'UK', ' United Kingdom']), ('USA', ['US', 'USA', 'United States']), ('BRA', ['Brazil', 'BR'])]
```